# Convert ddply in R to sparkR function

Tags: r, plyr, lapply, sparkr

I have a data frame `df` with millions of rows. I use `ddply` with user defined function `udf`.

```
res <- ddply(df, c("id"),function(x){udf(x)}
```

This works pretty well but it is extremely slow (it takes about 4 hours) I guess because of the `udf`. It checks a lot of cases.

I want to run the same function in sparkR. Spark is integrated in R environment. I can do basic operations in sparkR but couldn't find a function that can replace `ddply`. Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

With SparkR 2.0 you could use the [gapplyCollect](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/gapplyCollect.html) function to perform something like this (gruping by "id" and then applying your own functions over the columns of each row):

```
res <- gapplyCollect(
    df,
    "id",
    function(key, x) {
        y <- data.frame(key, max(x$column1), mean(x$column2), udf(x$column3))
        colnames(y) <- c("id", "max_col1", "mean_col2", "udf_result")
        y
    })
```

I hope this helps.